# How to check actual content length against Content-Length header?

Tags: http, node.js

A user can POST a document to our web service. We stream it elsewhere. But, at the end of the streaming, we need to be sure they didn't lie about their Content-Length.

I assume if `headerContentLength > realContentLength`, the request will just wait for them to send the rest, eventually timing out. So that's probably OK.

What about if `headerContentLength < realContentLength`? I.e. what if they keep sending data after they said they were done?

Is this taken care of by Node.js in any way? If not, what is a good way to check? I suppose I could just count up the bytes inside of some `data` event listeners---i.e., `req.on("data", function (chunk) { totalBytes += chunk.length; })`. That seems like a kludge though.

Comment: Are you not performing this check on the request's `end` event because you want to end the connection immediately in the event the client is sending more data than the `content-length` header specified?

Comment: I'd be happy to perform the check in the `end` event, but I don't know what property to access to tell how many bytes were really sent. `http.ServerRequest` doesn't seem to have any such property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check the actual length of the request, you have to add it up yourself. The `data` chunks are `Buffer`s and they have a `.length` property that you can add up.

If you specify the encoding with `request.setEncoding()`, your `data` chunks will be `String`s instead. In that case, call `Buffer.byteLength(chunk)` to get the length. (`Buffer` is a global object in node.)

Add up the total for each of your chunks and you'll know how much data was sent. 
Here's a rough (untested) example:

```
https.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var expected_length = req.headers['content-length']; // I think this is a string ;)
    var actual_length = 0;
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        actual_length += chunk.length;
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
        console.log('expected: ' + expected_length + ', actual: ' + actual_length);
    });
});
```

Note: `length` refers to the maximum length of the `Buffer`'s content, not the actual length. However, it works in this case because chunk buffers are always created at the exact correct length. Just be aware of that if you're working with buffers somewhere else.